# Opening a PDF in App Bundle in Safari ? iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, pdf, safari

I have a PDF document in my app which I want to allow users to view and email if required.

I would like to open the document in Safari which then should give me access to the forward action in the Safari PDF reader.

How can I open Safari and display the PDF ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

this just came to my mind that you won't be able to see the pdf as it is in the sandbox of your app and safari is a different app , so if you want to show it you can use a WebView instead safari... you can use this code instead...

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Comment: Think you're missing something in your code - nothing ever displays the PDF ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - displays "Failed to open url" even though file name is correct.

Comment: Webview is no good - see original question - I need to let the user email the document.

Comment: Yeah - although based on this question alone I guess you wouldn't guess - :D